# how can refresh a page remotly in javascript

Tags: javascript, browser-refresh

is there a way to refresh a page remotly from another page in javascript. i want to force the browser to do a refresh when i go back to a page which was displayed before. im doing some code in a page and it should show some results in another page, when i go to the page where i suppose to see the results, i have to press F5 to see them... so please help :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `location.reload(true)` *(reloads from the server)* or `location.reload()` *(reloads from cache)*

```
<a href="link_here" onclick="location.reload(true)">click me</a>
```

Hope this helps.